# java Clear Table on button click

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane

I am writing a Mortgage Calculator for class and I have it working the way I need it to, except everytime I click the "Calculate" button it will just continue to add to the table instead of the table clearing and showing new values. I know my code might look a little sloppy and I have some things commented out that don't need to be there because I'm still working it, but do you have any suggestions?

**FYI** I am still a beginner learning Java and it has taken me over 20hrs to get this far (and i"m pretty proud of myself!) Thank you!!

```
//Import all required Packages
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MortgageCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


// Loan Values
double intPrincipal, interestRate, calcPayment, monthlyInterest, currentInterest, principalPaid, newBalance;

int totalMonths;

double[] loanInterest = {5.35, 5.5, 5.75}; // Yearly interest in decimal form
int[] loanTerm = {7, 15, 30}; // Total months of term
String principal;
String comboArray[] = {"7 Years at 5.35%", "15 Years at 5.5%", "30 Years at 5.75%"};
int termYears, termMonths, done, i=0, m=0, p=0;



//Set up panels
JPanel contentPanel;

//Set up labels
JLabel mortgageLabel, paymentLabel, termLabel;

//Set up buttons
JButton calculateButton, clearButton, exitButton;

//TextFields
JTextField txtMortgage = new JTextField(10);
JTextField txtPayment = new JTextField(10);

//New Text Area
JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.00"); //Formatting the results to decimal form


//Combo Box
JComboBox loansList = new JComboBox();

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(model);

//Build GUI
    public MortgageCalculator()
    {
    super();
    initializeContent();
    }

    public void initializeContent()
                {
                    this.setSize(700, 500);
                    this.setLocation(0, 0);
                    this.setContentPane(contentPanel());
                    this.setTitle("Mortgage Calculator");
                }

    public JPanel contentPanel()
                {

                    contentPanel = new JPanel();
                    contentPanel.setLayout(null);


                    //Add labels to the  panel
                    mortgageLabel = new JLabel("Mortgage:");
                    mortgageLabel.setLocation(200, 30);
                    mortgageLabel.setSize(100, 25);
                    contentPanel.add(mortgageLabel);

                    termLabel = new JLabel("Term & Rate:");
                    termLabel.setLocation(183, 55);
                    termLabel.setSize(100, 30);
                    contentPanel.add(termLabel);

                    paymentLabel = new JLabel("Monthly Payment:");
                    paymentLabel.setLocation(158, 85);
                    paymentLabel.setSize(100, 30);
                    contentPanel.add(paymentLabel);

                    //Text Fields

                    txtMortgage = new JTextField(10);
                    txtMortgage.setLocation(280, 30);
                    txtMortgage.setSize(150, 25);
                    contentPanel.add(txtMortgage);

                    txtPayment = new JTextField(10);
                    txtPayment.setLocation(280, 85);
                    txtPayment.setSize(150, 25);
                    contentPanel.add(txtPayment);


                    //Combo Box

                    loansList.addItem(comboArray[0]);
                    loansList.addItem(comboArray[1]);
                    loansList.addItem(comboArray[2]);
                    loansList.setLocation(280, 55);
                    loansList.setSize(150, 25);
                    loansList.addActionListener(this);
                    contentPanel.add(loansList);


                    //textarea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 300));


                     //JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(textarea);
                     JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(table);
                     contentPanel.add(scroller);
                     scroller.setSize(650,300);
                     scroller.setLocation(20, 150);


                     textarea.setLineWrap(true);

                    model.addColumn("Payment Number");
                    model.addColumn("Current Interest");
                    model.addColumn("Principal Paid");
                    model.addColumn("New Balance");



                    //Buttons
                    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
                    exitButton.setLocation(450, 30);
                    exitButton.setSize(100, 25);
                    contentPanel.add(exitButton);

                    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
                    clearButton.setLocation(450, 55);
                    clearButton.setSize(100, 25);
                    contentPanel.add(clearButton);


                    calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
                    calculateButton.setLocation(450, 85);
                    calculateButton.setSize(100, 25);
                    contentPanel.add(calculateButton);

                    //setup up buttons
                    calculateButton.addActionListener(this);
                    clearButton.addActionListener(this);
                    exitButton.addActionListener(this);


                    return contentPanel;

                }




    //Define actions performed for buttons
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

            String arg = e.getActionCommand();
            if (e.getSource() == loansList) {
                switch (loansList.getSelectedIndex()) {
                        case 0:
                                i = 0;
                                break;
                        case 1:
                                i = 1;
                                break;
                        case 2:
                                i = 2;
                                break;
                }
            }

            if (arg == "Calculate")
            {

                txtPayment.setText("");
                principal = txtMortgage.getText();
                try {
                            intPrincipal = Double.parseDouble(principal);
                            if (intPrincipal <= 0) throw new NumberFormatException();
                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException n){
                            txtPayment.setText("Please Enter a Postive Numeric Number");
                            done = 1;
                    }
                if (done == 1)
                        done = 0;
                else {

                            interestRate = loanInterest[i];
                            termYears = loanTerm[i];
                            monthlyInterest = interestRate/(12*100); //calculates monthly interest
                            termMonths = termYears*12; //calculates term length in months
                            calcPayment = monthlyInterest*intPrincipal/(1-Math.pow((1+monthlyInterest), -termMonths)); //calculates monthly payment
                            txtPayment.setText(" " + df.format(calcPayment));

                            for (m=0; m<=totalMonths; m++) {
                                totalMonths = loanTerm[i]*12;
                                currentInterest = intPrincipal * monthlyInterest;
                                principalPaid = calcPayment - currentInterest;
                                newBalance = intPrincipal - principalPaid;
                                intPrincipal = newBalance;

                               /* printAndAppend(
                                (m+1) + "            " +
                                df.format(currentInterest) + "                        " +
                                df.format(principalPaid) + "            " +
                                df.format(newBalance) + "\n");
                                //textarea.setText(df.format(currentInterest));

                                if(intPrincipal <= 1){ break;}*/


                                // Create a couple of columns


                                model.addRow(new Object[]{m+1, df.format(currentInterest), df.format(principalPaid), df.format(newBalance)});

                                if(intPrincipal <= 1){ break;}



                            }


            }
    }

            else if (e.getSource() == clearButton)
            {
                txtMortgage.setText(""); //clear Mortgage textfield
                txtPayment.setText(""); //clear Payment textfield
                txtMortgage.requestFocusInWindow(); //move cursor back to Mortgage textfield
                loansList.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }

            else if (e.getSource() == exitButton)
                System.exit(0);
        }

    public void printAndAppend(String text) {
        textarea.append(text);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MortgageCalculator().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `model = new DefaultTableModel();` whenever you want to clear the table

Comment: I have that on the top of my code "DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();"   do I need to place that somewhere else?

Comment: add it before `for (m=0; m<=totalMonths; m++)`

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: you really don't need to create a new model.

Comment: @Eng creating a new model is not really a good idea because you lose any custom renderer or editor that was added to the table. You would also lose any TableModelListener that was added to the model. Also if the user has reordered any of the columns you would lose that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear all you need to do is set the row count of the model to 0 -- that's it:

```
  else if (e.getSource() == clearButton) {
     txtMortgage.setText(""); 
     txtPayment.setText(""); 
     txtMortgage.requestFocusInWindow(); 
     loansList.setSelectedIndex(0);

     model.setRowCount(0); //!! added
  }
```

Also, this is not good:

```
  if (arg == "Calculate") {
```

As you shouldn't use == to compare Strings. If you want to compare Strings, use the equals method:

```
  if (arg.equals("Calculate")) {
```

or the equalsIgnoreCase method:

```
  if (arg.equalsIgnoreCase("Calculate")) {
```

The reason this is important is because == checks to see if one String object is the same as another String object, and you really don't care about this. Instead you want to know if one String holds the same chars as another, and that's what equals tests for.

Also, I'd set the model's row count to 0 at the beginning of your calculate method, and this way you can recalculate things without having to clear.

Comment: @Dawn: you're welcome! Next we'll work on use of layout managers. :)

Comment: Whew, Java is one heck of a beast!! Though it is taking me a while to figure out how to write this program, I am having fun.